# Automatically edit specific section out and forward emails

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, forwarding

Is it possible to automatically strip unwanted text out of a message body and forward it to another email address? I currently receive a weekly list of songs to play on my radio show in a list from 1 - 20, and I want to automatically remove the email signatures, additional info and advertising from the bottom of the email and forward it to a predefined address to be automatically reblogged across my blog sites.

The email is worded exactly the same every week with a changing list, is it possible to forward only the header and the list?

For example:

> Top 20 songs
>   20 - led zepplin
>   19 - pink floyd
>   ...
>   1 - ac/dc
>
> Thanks, Programme Director [website link] [contact]

I want to remove the last line of that sample email above and forward the edited message to something like posterous to be reblogged.

I am currently manually editing and forwarding, but I'm struggling to keep up with it as I'm not always able to get to a computer.

Have [read previous topics](https://superuser.com/questions/80996/how-can-i-automatically-edit-an-email-before-auto-forwarding-it) [to no avail](http://powermail4joomla.com/forum/archive/index.php/thread-26.html), any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm currently using posterous to autoblog to my station profile pages, and using LetterMeLater.com as a workaround when I'm not at my computer. That is, when I have some free time I edit the message to be forwarded and copy to LetterMeLater to be resent on the night of the show, at the exact moment the show goes live to air.

This is great, and best of all free; however it would greatly help if I could automatically edit the messages somehow, the text string I want to remove is exactly the same every week and the content is always emailed in the exact same format/layout.

I will be happy to change mail programs, even operating systems to work around this, and I'm more than happy to exchange contact details / private message details and provide examples.

Any assistance would be most appreciated! I will continue to watch this thread and check back every few days, Thanks so much for your help and patience, and I look forward to any responses

Currently using Thunderbird 2.0 on Windows 7

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account

Answer (score 0):

You'd need three parts to this:

1. An app to automatically check email and save messages to text files.
2. Some sort of text processing to trim the headers and the signature lines from the saved emails.
3. An email app to send the email to your autoposter.

I'm not aware of any apps for step one, but there should be at least a few open source commandline options. For step two I would use Grep/Sed, maybe Awk. For step three, there are plenty of open source command line email apps, I use [BMail](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm) and [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

You will need to tie all this together with a batch script, or PowerShell I guess, and run it on a schedule.